# python multiprocessing, import txt files

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I'm dealing with Python multiprocessing and I'd like to understand if it is possible to save time with it.

I have three txt file that should be read by Python. So I defined a function that open a txt file and read it line by line. The input needed by this function is just the name of the txt file:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
output=mp.Queue()
def funct_imp(name):
     [...]
     output.put([var1,var2,var3])
     return (var1,var2,var3)
```

Then I compared the first script:

```
res01=funct_imp(name01)
res02=funct_imp(name02)
res03=funct_imp(name03)
```

With the second one in which I use Python multiprocessing:

```
for name in [name01,name02,name03]:
    pool=mp.Process(target=func_imp,args=name)
    pool.start()
    res=output.get()
```

Now I have two main questions:

1. How can I get results from all processes? At the end I find in `res` just the same results of `res03`
2. The first script runs in 18 sec, while the second runs in 25 sec. I expected it to be the opposite (actually I expected to reduce timing more).

Comment: I think you need to have a look at the multiprocessing documentation: [Python Multiprocessing](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html). The example of using a multiprocessing pool should be easily adapted to work for you

Comment: If the task itself is not time-expensive enough, the using of multiprocessing will make the overall processing time worse since the creation of the processes and then the inter-process communication is time expensive. So lets say that each process takes 1s to be created. If you create a process for a task that takes 0.1s to execute, the total execution time will be 1.1s with multiprocessing instead of 0.1s that it could take if you executed the task directly. Ofc, just an example. Also.. your code could be better, which I will answer properly :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def read_file(name):
   lines = []
   with open(name) as fp:
       lines = fp.readlines()
   return lines

if __name__ == '__main__':
    names = ['file1.txt', 'file2.txt']  # list of filenames
    pool = mp.Pool()
    results = pool.map(read_file, names)
```

This will read all lines into memory, use `pool.imap` for a lazier version, along with yielding lines in `read_file`.
`results` will be a list of list of lines.

Answer (score 0):

Try using multiprocessing Pool instead:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def f(x):
    -- process the file here --

if __name__ == '__main__':
    p = Pool()
    print(p.map(f, [name01, name02, name03]))
```

source: https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html